# Append tag to textarea as a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text area , now I want to append `"<if></if>"` as text each time I click some button , the 
problem is that when I use:

```
$("text area").append("<if></if>")
```

It is Appended as a child node , and not as text , any idea how can I make this ?? please put in mind that I want texts to be added so I cant use text() or html() , and don't want to create new div each time inside the text area.

Comment: Why not use .val() to add the text?

Comment: Do you mean $("textarea") ? Because $("text area") is another thing: jQuery will look for an AREA tag inside a TEXT tag.

Comment: no had just to put space cause stupid grammar check didnt let me use this one , don't know why !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the "value" property:

```
$('#yourTextarea').val($('#yourTextarea').val() + "<if></if>");
```

Though the initial value for a `<textarea>` comes from the content between the start and end tags, you subsequently manipulate the element via the "value" property.

*edit* — sorry the property name is indeed "value" but you mess with it via jQuery's `.val()`.